# Chrome Developer Tools > Metrics Pane

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

This page shows a `Metrics` pane: 
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/dom-and-styles

However, the latest version of Canary does not seem to have one. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `Metrics` **tab** is not separated any more, but Metrics **pane** is present in Developer tools.

Version *44.0.2368.0 canary (64-bit)* has it at the bottom of the `Styles` tab, or at the top of the `Computed` tab (when Developer tools is docked to bottom).

This is the case for standard Chrome (*41.0.2272.118 m*) as well.